# Switch layer when zooming

Tags: qgis, layers, zoom

I'm wondering if it is possible to set up a boundary on zooming for e.g. 3 different vector layers, so that when zooming in QGIS will automatically switch layer?

For example layer 1 has scale 1:450000, then when zooming in to scale 1:200000 QGIS will switch to layer 2 (having more details than layer 1) and when zooming in ot scale 1:20000 it will switch to layer 3.

Maybe this feature is about turning off layer 1 when reaching zooming scale of 1:200000 and so on...?

I'm using QGIS 2.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this feature is available under Properties > General > Scale dependent visibility. Set for each layer. The switch is only for visibility. The active layer in the TOC (Layer control) will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks!!! That solved my problem easilly. Basic stuff, but still learning ;-)